# LXC container cannot ping outside

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking, lxc

I'm currently creating a new container on a fresh server and I'm facing a network issue. Basically the container cannot reach anything on the Internet i.e. every request timeout.

Here are the information related to the host and the lxc configuration:

- `uname -r` output on the server: `4.9.185-xxxx-std-ipv6-64`.
- `lxc-ls --version`: `3.0.3`
- `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`: `1`
- `cat /etc/lxc/lxc.conf`:

```
lxc.lxcpath = /home/lxc
```

- `cat /etc/default/lxc-net`:

```
USE_LXC_BRIDGE="true"
LXC_BRIDGE="lxc-bridge-nat"
LXC_ADDR="192.168.100.1"
LXC_NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
LXC_NETWORK="192.168.100.0/24"
LXC_DHCP_RANGE="192.168.100.2,192.168.100.254"
LXC_DHCP_MAX="253"
LXC_DHCP_CONFILE=""
LXC_DOMAIN="lxc"

LXC_IPV6_ADDR="fc27::216:3eff:fe00:1"
LXC_IPV6_MASK="64"
LXC_IPV6_NETWORK="fc27::/64"
LXC_IPV6_NAT="true"
```

- `cat /home/lxc/test/config`

```
# Template used to create this container: /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-download
# Parameters passed to the template: -d debian -r buster -a amd64
# Template script checksum (SHA-1): 273c51343604eb85f7e294c8da0a5eb769d648f3
# For additional config options, please look at lxc.container.conf(5)

# Uncomment the following line to support nesting containers:
#lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/nesting.conf
# (Be aware this has security implications)

# Auto start configuration
# Mount shared folder so the container can access letsencrypt certificates
# into its own /share folder

# Distribution configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/common.conf
lxc.arch = linux64

# Container specific configuration
lxc.start.auto = 1
lxc.rootfs.path = dir:/home/lxc/test/rootfs
lxc.uts.name = test

# Network configuration
lxc.net.0.type  = veth
lxc.net.0.flags = up
lxc.net.0.link  = lxc-bridge-nat
```

With this setup I can successfully ping the container or the host from the container through the `lxc-bridge-nat` interface. But inside the container the command `ping 8.8.8.8` does not give any results:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
^C--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
18 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

Here is the iptables configuration on the host:

```
 Generated by xtables-save v1.8.3 on Wed Jul 17 11:10:37 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [245428:1063335794]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [228241:18791314]
:f2b-sshd - [0:0]
:f2b-recidive - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lxc-bridge-nat -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxc-bridge-nat -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxc-bridge-nat -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxc-bridge-nat -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -j f2b-recidive
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A FORWARD -o lxc-bridge-nat -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxc-bridge-nat -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -j f2b-recidive
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
-A f2b-recidive -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jul 17 11:10:37 2019
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.3 on Wed Jul 17 11:10:37 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 ! -d 192.168.100.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jul 17 11:10:37 2019
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.3 on Wed Jul 17 11:10:37 2019
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [248302:1063534761]
:INPUT ACCEPT [247677:1063489218]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [538:39768]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [228241:18791314]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [228779:18831082]
-A POSTROUTING -o lxc-bridge-nat -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jul 17 11:10:37 2019
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.3 on Wed Jul 17 11:10:37 2019
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3012:193211]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2048:239550]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jul 17 11:10:37 2019
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy-save to see them
```

I have also tried the `tcpdump -i eno1 -n icmp` command to see if there was any issue related to the IP packet and here is the output (It has been run on the host side during a ping to 8.8.8.8 on the container side):

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
11:12:38.938243 IP 192.168.100.78 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1137, seq 0, length 64
11:12:39.939343 IP 192.168.100.78 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1137, seq 1, length 64
11:12:40.940554 IP 192.168.100.78 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1137, seq 2, length 64
11:12:41.941748 IP 192.168.100.78 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1137, seq 3, length 64
11:12:42.942939 IP 192.168.100.78 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 1137, seq 4, length 64
```

Has you can see the packet goes on the Internet through the public interface but it is using the IP address of the container and not the host.

So I assume my issue is related to that but I don't know why it does that and how to fix it.

If you need any more information in order to solve my problem, feel free to ask.

------- EDIT: add iptables raw output
`iptables -nvL`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 251K packets, 1064M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  lxc-bridge-nat *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    6   430 ACCEPT     udp  --  lxc-bridge-nat *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  lxc-bridge-nat *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67
   16  5295 ACCEPT     udp  --  lxc-bridge-nat *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
 219K 1062M f2b-recidive  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 215K 1046M f2b-sshd   tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lxc-bridge-nat  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  131 10860 ACCEPT     all  --  lxc-bridge-nat *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 f2b-recidive  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 233K packets, 19M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 214K 1046M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain f2b-recidive (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  874 52624 REJECT     all  --  *      *       106.75.71.124        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
  246 14760 REJECT     all  --  *      *       51.75.23.87          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
 218K 1062M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
```

`iptables -nvL -t nat`

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.100.0/24    !192.168.100.0/24    

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
```

Comment: `-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 ! -d 192.168.100.0/24 -j MASQUERADE` is missing `-t nat`: `-t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 ! -d 192.168.100.0/24 -j MASQUERADE`.  `net.ipv4.ip_forward` is set to 1?

Comment: `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` -> `1`. The `MASQUERADE` rules is present in iptables

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `*nat`. I'd add `-o eno1` when using MASQUERADE. Do you have a static IP on `eno1`? Then use `SNAT` instead of MASQUERADE. Other than that, this all looks OK to me. Is there some iptables rule present that you don't know of? What's the output of `iptables -nvL` and `iptables -nvL -t nat`?

Comment: No problem. The `MASQUERADE` rule has been automatically created by `lxc-net` service so I don't think it is the issue but I will try anyway. I gave you the whole `iptables-save` output without removing anything. I add the output you've asked in the question anyway.

Comment: I just tried with the `-o eno1` option (and of course I have removed the previous rule) and nothing changes, still no ping to `8.8.8.8`

Comment: I tried to use SNAT rule (`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 ! -d 192.168.100.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source <public IP>`) instead of the `MASQUERADE` one and nothing changes, still no Internet access inside the container.

Comment: Like I said, I can't see anything wrong, then, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue (thank to tomp on https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org). By default lxc-net uses iptables to create rules which is fine but not working on my system because # Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them.

So after executing the command iptables-legacy -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 ! -d 192.168.100.0/24 -j MASQUERADE the system now works fine.

I now have two little more questions regarding this issue: why is this the case ? And how can I make this work using the non-legacy system ?